# Metric subspace M of compact metric space K is compact if every continuous f: M $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> If $M$ is a metric subspace of a compact metric space $K$ and every
>   continuous $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $M$ is
>   compact

I'm thinking of to prove this by showing $M$ is closed in $K$ and thus $M$ is compact since a closed subset of compact is compact.

I've got fix a point $a \in M' - M$ by supposing $M$ is not closed, and construct a continuous function

$f: M \to \mathbb{R}$

$f: x \mapsto \frac{1}{d_{K}(x, a)}$

this is not uniformly continuous since when $x \to a$, $f(x) \to \infty$, therefore this is a contradiction.

Is my proof correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: @Raptor Thanks for replying!